# Get supported document types

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

How do you get the list of all supported document types in a Cocoa app, programatically?

I expected to find this in `NSDocumentController` but the closest thing appears to be `documentClassNames`, a list of `NSDocument` subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 1:

If you open Project.-Info.plist then there you can find Document types.

And this is written is a plist (key-value pairs) you can simply get those values.

```
NSDictionary *infoDict=[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSArray *extensions=[infoDict valueForKeyPath:@"CFBundleDocumentTypes.CFBundleTypeExtensions"];
NSLog(@"ext:%@",extensions);
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that assume that I know the types beforehand?

Comment: Its your application and you only set what files it is going to read, isn't it :)

Comment: No, it's not my application. I'm developing a framework that will be used by the application.

Comment: I don't know the application beforehand, Anoop. I don't have access to its plist.

Comment: There's an -infoDictionary call on NSBundle--that will give you the bundle's plist. Call it on the main bundle after your framework is loaded

Comment: @nielsbot: That is what I have edited 5 minutes ago...is it good ?